# TBB possible memory leak

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-leaks, valgrind, tbb

Test program:

```
#include <tbb/parallel_invoke.h>

int main(void)
{
    tbb::parallel_invoke([]{},[]{});
    return 0;
}
```

1. Compiled using `g++ -std=c++11  tmp.cpp -ltbb`
2. Checked with

   ```
   valgrind --tool=memcheck --track-origins=yes \
            --leak-check=full --log-file=report ./a.out`
   ```
3. `libtbb` version: `4.0`, `valgrind` version: `3.8.1`.

Part of the above test result:

```
possibly lost: 1,980 bytes in 6 blocks
```

Question is:

Is this a `TBB` bug?

Or is this `possible lost` actually safe, it's just some codes that valgrind does not consider safe?

Comment: I also have problems with memory leaks when I use tbb.

Comment: Same problem but only since I upgraded TBB to 4.3. It was working without leaks before with 4.2. I detect the leak using VLD. I suspect that the tasks are just not destroyed at all when the scheduler ends running.

Comment: There is definitely a memory leak in TBB: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19273543/tbb-memory-leaks-when-using-inside-of-mfc-application

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, it's a false positive, not a bug. There are at least few reasons:

1. TBB uses its own memory allocator `libtbbmalloc`, it caches the memory till the process termination and can appear as a leak.
2. TBB threads run and terminate asynchronously. It is likely that after `main()` termination, the worker threads are still running. It leads to the same impression for the valgrind

In order to reasonably accuse TBB for a leak, exclude the above factors, e.g:

1. remove libtbbmalloc.so.2 or tbbmalloc.dll file so running an application with env.variable `TBB_VERSION=1` will output `TBB: ALLOCATOR  malloc` but not `TBB: ALLOCATOR  scalable_malloc`
2. make sure all the TBB threads are terminated

For example

```
int main()
{
    assert(tbb::tbb_allocator<int>::allocator_type() != tbb::tbb_allocator<int>::scalable);
    { // TBB scope
        tbb::task_scheduler_init scope;
        tbb::parallel_invoke([]{},[]{});
    } // TBB threads start termination here
    sleep(10); // wait for threads to terminate
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about in environments where inserting `sleep(10)` at the end of main won't pass code review? Is there a workaround for this issue, that would allow me to use TBB *and* valgrind *but not* `sleep(10)`? For example, some way to ask TBB to block until all worker threads are shut down cleanly?

Comment: it's the way to diagnose the problem, not to use in production of course

Comment: @Quuxplusone, there is preview feature which allows to wait for threads to terminate. So, *if* sleep solves the problem, you might consider this blocking termination feature of `tbb::task_scheduler_init` to do the same without sleep()