# TBB memory leaks when using inside of MFC application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-leaks, mfc, tbb

Hello stackoverflower,

Operation system: Windows 7 x64 SP1; TBB version: 4.2.0; Compiler: Visual Studio 2012.

Problem description:

TBB dumps memory leaks on the exit of MFC application. The same code doesn't dump any leaks, when used from simple command line program. It looks like a DLL unload order problem. Due to late tbb.dll unloading the debuger dumps some static variables as leaks.

Can someone confirm this issue? Is there any work around?

I also posted this question to [Intel forum](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/476407). There you can find the both test applications: command line and MFC.

Here is the memory dump:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{608} normal block at 0x00457970, 36 bytes long.
 Data: <T B B   W o r k > 54 00 42 00 42 00 20 00 57 00 6F 00 72 00 6B 00
{607} normal block at 0x00457918, 28 bytes long.
 Data: <    pyE         > 00 00 00 00 70 79 45 00 98 0F 00 00 00 00 00 00
{605} normal block at 0x0044ED98, 36 bytes long.
 Data: <T B B   W o r k > 54 00 42 00 42 00 20 00 57 00 6F 00 72 00 6B 00
{590} normal block at 0x00450AD8, 28 bytes long.
 Data: <      D         > 00 00 00 00 98 ED 44 00 04 20 00 00 00 00 00 00
{583} normal block at 0x00455AD8, 36 bytes long.
 Data: <T B B   W o r k > 54 00 42 00 42 00 20 00 57 00 6F 00 72 00 6B 00
{582} normal block at 0x00455A80, 28 bytes long.
 Data: <     ZE  .      > 00 00 00 00 D8 5A 45 00 98 2E 00 00 00 00 00 00
{580} normal block at 0x00455860, 36 bytes long.
 Data: <T B B   W o r k > 54 00 42 00 42 00 20 00 57 00 6F 00 72 00 6B 00
{579} normal block at 0x00455808, 28 bytes long.
 Data: <    `XE         > 00 00 00 00 60 58 45 00 EC 18 00 00 00 00 00 00
{569} normal block at 0x00453EC8, 36 bytes long.
 Data: <T B B   W o r k > 54 00 42 00 42 00 20 00 57 00 6F 00 72 00 6B 00
{568} normal block at 0x00453E70, 28 bytes long.
 Data: <     >E  0      > 00 00 00 00 C8 3E 45 00 FC 30 00 00 00 00 00 00
{566} normal block at 0x00453C50, 36 bytes long.
 Data: <T B B   W o r k > 54 00 42 00 42 00 20 00 57 00 6F 00 72 00 6B 00
{565} normal block at 0x0044D338, 28 bytes long.
 Data: <    P<E         > 00 00 00 00 50 3C 45 00 D8 08 00 00 00 00 00 00
{546} normal block at 0x0044F248, 36 bytes long.
 Data: <T B B   W o r k > 54 00 42 00 42 00 20 00 57 00 6F 00 72 00 6B 00
{536} normal block at 0x00451128, 28 bytes long.
 Data: <    H D  !      > 00 00 00 00 48 F2 44 00 14 21 00 00 00 00 00 00
{531} normal block at 0x00450518, 36 bytes long.
 Data: <T B B   W o r k > 54 00 42 00 42 00 20 00 57 00 6F 00 72 00 6B 00
{530} normal block at 0x004504C0, 28 bytes long.
 Data: <      E T!      > 00 00 00 00 18 05 45 00 54 21 00 00 00 00 00 00
{528} normal block at 0x00450290, 36 bytes long.
 Data: <T B B   W o r k > 54 00 42 00 42 00 20 00 57 00 6F 00 72 00 6B 00
{527} normal block at 0x00450238, 28 bytes long.
 Data: <      E 8       > 00 00 00 00 90 02 45 00 38 18 00 00 00 00 00 00
{518} normal block at 0x0044EE68, 36 bytes long.
 Data: <T B B   W o r k > 54 00 42 00 42 00 20 00 57 00 6F 00 72 00 6B 00
{517} normal block at 0x0044EE10, 28 bytes long.
 Data: <    h D  2      > 00 00 00 00 68 EE 44 00 B0 32 00 00 00 00 00 00
{507} normal block at 0x0044B190, 36 bytes long.
 Data: <T B B   W o r k > 54 00 42 00 42 00 20 00 57 00 6F 00 72 00 6B 00
{505} normal block at 0x0044D3B0, 28 bytes long.
 Data: <      D  '      > 00 00 00 00 90 B1 44 00 18 27 00 00 00 00 00 00
Object dump complete.
The program '[12168] TbbMfcTest.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Try [VLD](https://vld.codeplex.com/) which helps greatly finding memory leaks. It's very easy to use.

Comment: @Michael It won't help here. The problem is that MFC assumes to be the last library to unload (and was probably right about that for roughly a decade). When MFC unloads it performs its leak detection. While it is rather involved to control the order in which libraries unload, MFC will report false leaks when it isn't the final library to unload. That's what's happening here.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: I'm aware of VLD and already tried it for the problem analysis. But as IInspectable mentioned, this will not help here!

Comment: @IInspectable: Thanks for the confirmation! I also came to this conclusion. But i wondering if there any work around? Currently i don't see any, without changing the TBB interface.

Comment: @IInspectable: while it is true that MFC might report false leaks if unload too early, it seems that this is not the case here (see my answer below). B.t.w. you can trick loading MFC as first (and hence unloaded as last) to prevent false memory leak reporting.

Comment: @gas: Windows does not guarantee LIFO ordering for unloading modules.

Comment: @IInspectable: I don't know that but in our applications (>10) loading the MFC DLL first resulted in unloaded as last.

Comment: @gas: By chance, not by contractual guarantees. Modules are reference counted after all, to allow them to unload in the correct order, which may or may not be the reverse order they were loaded in.

Comment: @ IInspectable: I have never came across a situation where this didn't work. So 'chance' is a bit euphemistic. Pity if it doesn't work for you but other users might benefit from it. Be aware though that the TBB leak is most likely not MFC reporting related.

Answer (score 1):

If you spy the TBB sources, it seems that TBB allocates a memory block without proper releasing it (i.e. market::create_one_job() allocates a name for h->nameW with _wcsdup(name)).

If this is indeed the case, it would be best if one reports this to Intel but be warned that one might get into a discussion if this is indeed a true memory leak. We like to keep zero memory dump reports in the output window, because soon one can't distinguish the real ones with the harmless ones.